# Augmented Lagrangian with multiple constraints

Tags: convex-optimization

I would like to minimise a function, with multiple constraints:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \|y-Ax\|_2^2 + \beta \|z\|_1 $$

subject to

$$ Bx = 0 $$ **and** $$ x - z = 0 $$

In my case $(B+I)$ is not a valid matrix.

Do I just form the augmented Lagrangian as:

$$ L_{\rho} = \frac{1}{2} \|y-Ax\|_2^2 + \beta \|z\|_1 + \theta^T(x-z) + \frac{\rho}{2}\|x-z\| + \nu^T(Bz) + \frac{\rho}{2}\|Bz\| $$

?

Comment: Why not just do $$\begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ I & -I \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ z \end{bmatrix} = 0$$

Comment: Actually, I worked it out - but this still helps!

Comment: That's great! Of course, your inner product terms above are exactly equivalent to my "combined" linear equation. But my approach results in a "combined" norm term.

Comment: The $$\theta^T(x-z)$$ and $$\nu^T(Bx)$$ terms?

Comment: Right. My single equality constraint ends up with this:$$\begin{bmatrix} \nu \\ \theta \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ I & -I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ t \end{bmatrix}.$$ The norm ends up as $$\left\| \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ I & -I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ t \end{bmatrix} \right\|.$$

Comment: Thanks! This, is actually really helpful.

Comment: Wonderful, I'm glad to hear it. If you don't mind I'll collect my comments into an answer :-)

Comment: That would be brilliant! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that you don't really have two separate constraints here—or rather, you don't *need* to consider them as two separate constraints. Treat them instead as a single equality constraint
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ I & -I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ z \end{bmatrix} = 0\end{equation}
The good news is that your Lagrange multipliers need not change, and the inner products are exactly equivalent to yours. Only the norm terms change. 
The new augmented Lagrangian is
\begin{equation}
L_\rho = \tfrac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|_2^2+\beta\|z\|_1+
\begin{bmatrix} \nu \\ \theta \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ I & -I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ z \end{bmatrix} + \tfrac{\rho}{2}\left\|
\begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ I & -I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ z \end{bmatrix}\right\| \end{equation}
Actually, my memory may be hazy, but my understanding is it is standard practice to square the norm of the constraint term:
\begin{equation}
L_\rho = \tfrac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|_2^2+\beta\|z\|_1+
\begin{bmatrix} \nu \\ \theta \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ I & -I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ z \end{bmatrix} + \tfrac{\rho}{2}\left\|
\begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ I & -I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ z \end{bmatrix}\right\|_2^2 \end{equation}
If you had done this with your original approach above, you would find that your augmented Lagrangian is is *precisely* the same as this.